# Расчёт разницы во времени между двумя ячейками

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

С программирование на Google apps script знаком очень поверхностно, на основе своих знаний написал такой код (сразу скажу работает не корректно):

```
function ResponseTime(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetName();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var data = range.getValues(); 
  if(sheetName == "Вопросник" && range.getColumn() == 17){
    for (var i=0;i < data.length;i++){
      if (data[i][0]>0) {
        (data[i][0])=Date.parse(data[i][0]); 
        var time1 = (data[i][0])}
      else {
      }
    }
  }
  if(sheetName == "Вопросник" && range.getColumn() == 18){
    for (var i=0;i < data.length;i++){
      if (data[i][0]>0) {
        (data[i][0])=Date.parse(data[i][0]); 
        var time2 = (data[i][0])}
      else {
      }
    } 
   for (var i=0;i < data.length;i++){
      if (data[i][0]>0 && time2>0) {
        let date = new Date(time2);
        range.offset(i,+1,1,1).setValue(date.getHours()+':'+date.getMinutes());}
      else {
      }
   }
  }
}
```

У меня в таблице в столбцах 17 и 18 идут две даты, как рассчитать разницу между ними особо не нашел, поэтому решил сначала из обеих ячеек получить таймстамп с помощью Date.parse(str), далее уже найти разницу в миллисекундах и преобразовать ее в "часы:минуты".
Но в итоге что планировал получить не удалось. Я так понимаю основная проблема с методом .getColumn() он позволяет работать с определенным диапазоном, то есть только с одним столбцом и мне не подходит.
Подскажите на какой метод его заменить? и также я предполагаю что много лишнего написал в коде, может его как-то можно упростить, что-то выбросить?
Возможно я изначально пошел не по тому пути и все можно реализовать намного проще?
Буду рад любым предложениям.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Время находится в столбцах A & B, Разница записывается в столбец C.

```
function diffDates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Вопросник'); // ss.getActiveSheet();

  sheet.getRange('C:C').setValues(
    sheet
    .getRange('A:B')
    .getValues()
    .map(function(row){
      if (row[0] && row[1]) {
        return [msToTime(Math.abs(row[0] - row[1]))];
      }
      else return [''];
    })
  );
}

function msToTime(duration) {
  var seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60),
    minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
    hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

  hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
  minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

  return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

Функция `msToTime` взята [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19700358/7751274)

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно)  А нет мыслей как исключить из рассчитываемого периода выходные дни?

Comment: Используйте [getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) на дате и если день равен 0 или 6 - то игнорить